# What is the difference between normal and contact forces?

Tags: forces, contact-mechanics

What is the difference between normal and contact forces? Isn't the contact force exactly equal to the normal force? I don't see how some contact forces aren't perpendicular to the object they are acting upon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A contact force is any force that objects exert on one another because they make physical contact. But only the component of the contact force that is perpendicular to the surface is a normal force.

Friction is an example of a contact force. But it acts parallel to a surface. On the other hand, the magnitude of the kinetic friction force, and the maximum possible value of the static friction force, depends on the product of the force perpendicular to the surface, which is the normal force, times the applicable coefficient of friction.

Hope this helps;.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand it now.